# Função shell script

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script

Tenho uma VM e preciso executar um script remotamente em outra VM, exemplo:

Script está na VM X e preciso executar pela X na VM Y.

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=$1

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
echo "informe o servidor $1: "
exit

fi

for machine in $1; do

    ssh -l root -o ConnectTimeout=2 $machine ifconfig

done
```

Esse comando executa corretamente e é isso que preciso, porem preciso executar uma função com uma regra de negocio.

Parecido como este:

```
    for machine in $1; do

    ssh -l root -o ConnectTimeout=2 $machine funcao1

done 


function funcao1{

mkdir teste

cd teste
}
```

Alguém sabe me informar uma solução parecida ? Ou similar ?

Vlw!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode resolver isso fazendo dois scripts. O primeiro é responsável por percorrer a lista de máquinas e executar o ssh. O segundo contém o código da `funcao1`.

Shell script 1 (script1.sh):

```
for machine in $1; do
  ssh -l root -o ConnectTimeout=2 $machine 'bash -s' < script2.sh "teste" "parametro"
done
```

Shell script 2 (script2.sh):

```
mkdir teste
cd teste
echo $1 $2
```

Note que o `ssh` é feito com a opção `'bash -s'`. Esta opção permite que um script seja executado remotamente na máquina para qual o `ssh` é feito. O script não precisa estar localmente na máquina remota. Portanto, o `scritp1.sh` e `script2.sh` devem ficar ambos na máquina master (a máquina que faz o ssh).

Comment: obrigado pela resposta.

Infelizmente não me atende, no exemplo anterior não coloquei o código que realmente vou usar na função mas vou usar parâmetros de entrada incluindo o parâmetro $1.  No exemplo que você passou não consigo usar os parâmetros de entrada inicial no segundo arquivo script2.sh.

Comment: Vou editar o conteúdo.

Comment: @tharleycarvalho, por isso é importante fazer uma pergunta bem completa, com todos os detalhes relevantes. Fica a dica. Sobre o seu problema, atualizei a resposta com a possibilidade de passar parametros. Favor verificar.

Comment: Obrigado @cantoni. É possivel receber o valor da $1 (máquina) no outro arquivo script2.sh onde ficara o código ?

Comment: Passe o nome da variavel, ao invés de uma string: ssh -l root -o ConnectTimeout=2 $machine 'bash -s' < script2.sh $1 $machine

Comment: ainda aqui ? Me tire uma dúvida, por que não consigo passar uma variável parâmetro string ? Exemplo: sshpass -p $PASSWDFTP ssh -l $USERNAME -o ConnectTimeout=2 $machine 'bash -s' < teste.sh $USERNAME $HOSTNAME $PASSWD;   Essas Variáveis não são transferida para o teste.sh, mas se eu colocar $1 $2 $3 são transferido os valores. O meu problema é: Não consigo atribuir valores a essas variáveis .

Comment: Para ser mais exato, eu consigo só passar parâmetros como $1, variável em si não consegui de nenhuma forma.

Comment: @tharleycarvalho, se entendi bem sua pergunta, você está tentando referenciar (dentro do script2.sh) o nome das variáveis que você passa no script1.sh? Se você está tentando, dentro do script2.sh, usar $USERNAME, isso realmente não vai funcionar. Dentro do script2.sh, você tem $1, $2, $n (onde n é o numero de parametros). O que você pode fazer, portanto, é dentro do script2.sh declarar uma variável que se chama $USERNAME e atribuíla o valor de $1, apenas para ficar mais claro para quem está lendo o scritp2.sh.